# Tap Event for Pin Annotation Callout View

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

What method should I use to handle if the Pin Annotation's view gets clicked?

I am able to get the disclosure button hooked up to this:

```
myPinAnnotationView.canShowCallout = YES

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
```

How do I get the Callout View to trigger a tap event?

Answer (score 0):

1. Implement extension MKMapViewDelegate
2. Implement method func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView)
3. Put whatever functionality you need/desire within that method